# Is there a way to remove abilities to delete/modify documents uploaded to DocuSign on the Sender View?

Tags: docusignapi

I am using the DocuSign REST API v2 with the DocuSign Java Client. I am providing a user with the DocuSign Sender view to let them finish the rest, such as adding Signature or change email subject/body. The rule that I want to apply to the Sender view is that a sender should not modify or remove document(s) uploaded to DocuSign on the Sender view but can change the order of documents.
To achieve that, I created a permission set for the sender to restrict some abilities of the Sender View. I couldn't find an option for modifying documents.

[Current Permissions set that I am using](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fjzzw.png)

The following is the current Sender view that I created with the above permission set. I would like to remove the abilities of the square boxes in red.

[The sender view that I am testing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I3P3m.png)

As far as I research, it seems that there is no way to remove abilities to delete/modify documents uploaded to DocuSign on the Sender View. If you have any experiences in terms of this, could you please advise on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that "Disable Document Upload" still allows the "Replace Document" option is currently being handled as a product issue. I don't have a timeline for resolution, but if you like you can contact your Account Manager to have them add your account's info to the internal ticket for this: MAR-29446

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. Does "Your Account Manager" mean a person who creates my DocuSign account?

Comment: Yes, it would be your contact on the DocuSign side. If you've purchased a web account, you can open a Support Case (https://support.docusign.com/) to request your account be added.